# C - 'char **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[6]'

Tags: c

Can someone please explain to me what's wrong with the following, and more importantly why?

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char array[] = "array";
    char **test;
    test = &array;

    *test[0] = 'Z';

    printf( "%s\n", array );

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

My example above was based on a function like this that was crashing:

```
void apple( char **pp )
{
    *pp = malloc( 123 );
    *pp[0] = 'a'; // technically this is correct but in bad form
    *pp[1] = 'b'; // incorrect but no crash
    *pp[2] = '\0'; // incorrect and crash
}
```

As pointed out to me by Vaughn Cato although `*pp[0] = 'a';` does not crash it is in bad form. The correct form is the parenthesis

```
void apple( char **pp )
{
    *pp = malloc( 123 );
    (*pp)[0] = 'a'; // correct
    (*pp)[1] = 'b'; // correct
    (*pp)[2] = '\0'; // correct
}
```

Also as another poster MK pointed out the FAQ covers the difference between arrays and pointers:
http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Comment: Actually that's a `char (*)[6]`.

Comment: @Mysticial one word: everything :)

Comment: Do you mean, why is that conversion not allowed?

Comment: Why do you want a `char **test` to `char[]` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`test = &array`

is wrong because test is of type `char**` and `&array` is a `char(*)[6]` and is a different type from `char**`

An array isn't the same type as `char*` although C will implicitly convert between an array type and a `char*` in some contexts, but this isn't one of them. Basically the expectation that `char*` is the same as the type of an array (e.g: `char[6]`) is wrong and therefore the expectation that taking the address of an array will result in a `char**` is also wrong.

Comment: Given `char array[] = "array";`, it is actually a pointer to an array of size 6, not 5, even though the question title says '5'.

Comment: yeah jon I modified the example so you are right it is size 6 and not 5

Comment: Furthermore even if you have the right pointer type, you cannot modify a string literal. Even though it will work on some questionable old compilers for PC, it is very bad practice and possible undefined behavior(?).

Answer (score 5):

This would be the way to do what you seem to be trying to do:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  char array[] = "array";
  char (*test)[6];
  test = &array;

  (*test)[0] = 'Z';

  printf( "%s\n", array );

  return 0;
}
```

test is a pointer to an array, and an array is different from a pointer, even though C makes it easy to use one like the other in my cases.

If you wanted to avoid having to specify a specific sized array, you could use a different approach:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  char array[] = "array";
  char *test;
  test = array;  // same as test = &array[0];

  test[0] = 'Z';

  printf( "%s\n", array );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have already marked another answer as correct that goes into detail but I like that you posted the solution. I am curious though, as I tried this myself but with a slight variation... how come I can't do something like char (*test)[] without the actual character count? What if I don't know it?

Comment: In that case, you would probably just use a char *.  I've added an example to this answer.

Comment: Well I've got this function that has a parameter like `char **super` and in the function *super points to a string. I can't do something like `*super[0]='Z'` or `**super='Z'` and I am wondering how I can do that. I can't change the parameter type.

Comment: Technically, *super[0]='Z' would work, but most likely you mean to do (*super)[0]='Z'

Comment: A ha! So they both work, that's what was so confusing. `*super[0]='Z'` and `(*super)[0]='Z'` both work in the test case. Of course `*super[1]='Z'` does not work where `(*super)[1]='Z'` does due to operator precedence rules. I'm going to update my question for anyone in a similar situation and I'll credit you in the edit. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`char **test;` is a pointer to a pointer, but if you're going to take the address of an entire array then it needs to be a pointer to entire array i.e `char (*test)[6];`