# char* differs in levels of indirection from char(*)[100]

Tags: c, char, indirection

basically I am taking user input and using it to delete from a list, when this error has just been thrown. The code was working literally an hour ago so I don't know why Visual studio is now chucking a fit about it.

```
char courseName[100];
scanf("%s", courseName);
deletefromlist(&list, &courseName);
```

`deletefrom` list function takes `(Courselist * self, char * data)` as arguments.

How can i correct this error and in future avoid it? cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - 'char \*\*' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (\*)\[6\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524070/c-char-differs-in-levels-of-indirection-from-char-6)

Answer (score 5):

Second argument of function accepts `char *`, so you should pass `courseName` instead of `&courseName`.

Or depending on the nature of `deletefromlist`, you may want to change the argument type.

Comment: yea I tried that one, the code still breaks. Ill have to have a look at my delete function more perhaps. But why isn't char * not the same as char(*)? since theyre both pointing to something

Comment: You declared `courseName` as an array of `char`, so `courseName` behaves (almost) like a `char *` pointer (it points to the first `char` of the array). In your delete function, make sure you have the correct safeguards to avoid overflow when you treat the array.

Comment: ah yea, that makes sense since im getting memory access violations. cheers mate

Comment: Array when passed as argument to a function, depletes to the pointer to first element in array.